# Handle fatal error during function calling

Tags: php

I have an program which is generating pdf reports with cron job. now sometimes fatal error is coming and i am trying to handle that with try catch block

```
$pdfcalass->display();
$pdfcalass->Output("$filename",'F');
```

i need to handle the fatal error generating in calling two function.
i have tried this

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction',$request_id);
$pdfcalass->display();
$pdfcalass->Output("$filename",'F');
```

But Not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

To get the last error in php [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php):

```
function shutdownFunction($request_id){
    // something with $request_id;
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction', $request_id);
```

Comment: I  need to handle it like try catch

Comment: if error come update its status failed and return true

Comment: @Deepesh [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928487/php-try-catch-and-fatal-error) link might be helpful to you.

Comment: @Deepesh and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)