# Try catch with PHP generate error

Tags: php, database, exception, try-catch

I'm new to try and catch in PHP. When I tried it I expected all the warnings and errors in the `$e` variable. They are logged in `$e` but also output on the screen.

My current solution for it is to add `@` before `$db` to prevent the warnings from popping up on the screen. Is there a better solution? Mine feels a little hacky.

```
<?php
function db() {
    $db = array();
    try {
        @$db = new Database(array(
            'type'     => 'mysql',
            'host'     => 'localhosts',
            'database' => 'megastore',
            'user'     => 'root',
            'password' => ''
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    return $db;
}
```

Comment: Exceptions and errors aren't the same thing: try/catch will catch Exceptions, not errors, unles you've explicitly set up an error handler to convert errors to exceptions

Comment: What database extension are you using? `mysql_` or `mysqli_` or `PDO`?

Comment: Error handling has changed in v7: http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php

Comment: Don't supress errors using `@`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Don't blanket-ban `@`. Example: `$result = @file_put_contents("file.txt","derp"); if( !$result) presentUsefulErrorMessage();`. A proper error handler is definitely a good idea, but sometimes you need localised error handling that just isn't possible without `@`... at least until PHP7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP try/catch and fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928487/php-try-catch-and-fatal-error)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using mysql from a wrapper. https://getkirby.com/docs/toolkit/databases.

Comment: @AlexBlex I will use old PHP for some time but thanks for heads up.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul. Okay. Can you give alternatives then?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ah, good point. Noted. :)

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: The PDO extension comes with Exceptions already Baked in, use that especially as the `mysql_` extension IS DEAD as of PHP7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the silence operator is not a good idea.
You can use [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)() to show only what you want or you can set display_error (using [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)() or from php.ini) to false so error will not be display on the screen.
EDIT : 
This two options is not the same but maybe you can have the same results.
For more info read link in php manual.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this is a better idea than @ and that this is the best idea in this case?

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://github.com/getkirby/kirby/issues/360 "The database class is already built around PDO. The old mysql_ extension is not in use."