# How to manage Mysql constraint fail errors?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling, constraints

I have a PHP script and some constraint rules in Mysql to prevent the user from deleting a category that contains products.
But when the user try to delete the prohibited category he will face a fatal error instead of the website page

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails...
```

I need to show an error like below instead of Fatal error:

> You can not delete this category while it has products related.

Edit : note that the try/catch will not work for fatal errors

Comment: Depending on the logic of your site, it may be better to disable the delete button when something can't be deleted (check for dependant products when displaying the page).

Comment: If i have to check the related products every time , then why should i use the constraint rules?

Comment: Database rules are to ensure the database is correctly set up, (IMHO) business rules are more for the user.

Comment: Why not catch that error and map it to a readable message?

Comment: You cannot catch fatal errors using try/catch.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the _products_ when you delete the _category_? Presumably they should also be deleted? So just update the constraint to `cascade`??

Comment: I need to prevent user from deleting the category

Answer (score -1):

You can either put your query in a `try` and `catch` statement and try to catch all errors that occur during the query:

```
try{
//query
}
catch(Error $error){
//do something
}
```

Or put a error handler for your whole document:

```
function myCustomErrorHandler(int $errNo, string $errMsg, string $file, int $line) {
//do something
}

set_error_handler('myCustomErrorHandler');
```

I've got the idea originally from this website:
https://netgen.io/blog/modern-error-handling-in-php

Comment: It can be difficult with a global error handler to provide some meaningful error.

Comment: true, but useful if you just want to relay the user to a specific site, if an error occurs. In this case, if he wants to display an error message, it wouldn't really be viable.

Comment: I used try catch but i faced the fatal error again

Comment: then please use the `error_handler`, I just read that the `try catch` method can not handle fatal errors ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928487/php-try-catch-and-fatal-error?rq=1)), sorry for the confusion

Comment: He literally pasted the error and it says `fatal error`. The code isn't buggy at all